# How to remove spaces in Google Sheets query results

Tags: google-sheets

The following is combining the results of several cells (F:T) into one cell down several rows. How can I remove any blank spaces that result from combining the cells?

```
=transpose(
     query(
        transpose(F:T),,9^9
     )
)
```

I know I can use the TRIM() function, but I'm not sure how to include it in the Query.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F:T),,9^9)), " ", ))
```

Comment: One more thing... let's say I have a result like "Outdoor_Recreation" is it possible to replace the "_" with a blank, after I have removed all the other leading and trailing blanks?

Comment: @HighlandRanger sure: `=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F:T),,9^9)), " ", ), "_", " ")`

Answer (score 0):

You already know the answer, just use trim, you will notice an array error, to resolve this you just wrap the entire thing in an arrayformula:

```
=arrayformula(trim(transpose( query( transpose(F:I),,9^9 ) )))
```

Be careful with query if the majority of your data in a particular column will ever be numbers it will delete the text.

Comment: That didn't Trim the results, just the source cells which doesn't have any blank spaces. So what this is doing is taking the data that is in cells F:T, and in any one Row there is only ONE source of Data. So, on Row 1 the data may be in F2, while on Row 2 the data may be in M3 and what ends up happening is F3, G3, H3, etc ends up adding blank spaces to my result.

Comment: @HighlandRanger you need to include example data in your question as my sample data trims the entire result just fine. Sample Data -> Desired Output, you can over simplify it to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @HighlandRanger I modified the original answer to simply trim the query result since it sounds like you are saying you have data with blank cells and you want those blank cells trimmed as well in the final result. Try it now and tell me if it works.